# How to clear the entire workbook's conditional formatting by openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I wrote some code to do the conditional formatting. However, whenever I run the code, the cell are written with same conditional formatting once. Is there any way to clear the existing ones and write the new.

I have checked the offical documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html
but no clear function inside

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to clear the formatting for a particular worksheet you just need to create a new list:

```
from openpyxl.formatting.formatting import ConditionalFormattingList
ws.conditional_formatting = ConditionalFormattingList()
```

Comment: How do you just remove a single one?

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If You just want to remove the conditional formatting from specific cell/cell_range then,
follow this steps to remove conditional formatting.

```
wb = load_workbook("excel_file_path.xlsx")
ws = wb["sheet1"]
red_color = 'ffc7ce'
red_color_font = '9c0103'
red_font = styles.Font(size=14, bold=True, color=red_color_font)
red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=red_color, end_color=red_color, 
            fill_type='solid')
# to get all cf_rules 
cf_rl = list(ws.conditional_formatting._cf_rules)

#to get specific cell from list of formatting
l1 = [i for i in cf_rl if i.sqref == "F51"]

#to delete conditional formatting from specific cell
del ws.conditional_formatting._cf_rules[l1[0]]

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```